# Scoped style in vue.js isn't scoped at all

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Good afternoon,

I'm having a difficulty scoping imported CSS file within bounds of my HTMLEditor vue component.

Here's the component:

```
<template>
    <div class="htmleditor">
        <div class="htmleditor-input">
            <h3>Header</h3>
            <p>Paragraph of text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="htmleditor-output">

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default
    {
        data: () =>
        ({
            html: ''
        }),
    }
</script>

<style scoped src="~/css/default.min.css">
    .htmleditor
    {
        display: flex;
    }

    .htmleditor-input
    {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }

    .htmleditor-output
    {
        border: 1px solid yellow;
    }
</style>
```

The issue I'm having is, if I do it this way - it says

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~/css/default.min.css'

If I try putting @import '~/css/default.min.css' inside .htmleditor in CSS, all I get is a non-scoped style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix.
If you are getting the same error - know that nodejs' vue compiler requires somewhat 'absolute' paths to files.

You can't use '~/' nor '/' nor '.' as the first thing in your path, you have to navigate directly - which in my case (Laravel) meant putting: '../../../../css/default.min.css'.